# SQL Error #1007

Tags: mysql

I have this #1007 error with my SQL code. When I try to import into my database it gives me this #1007 error. The data base is called company. I'm new to SQL and it would be good if someone could help me out. Thanks

```
CREATE DATABASE company;
CREATE TABLE login(
id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: What platform? SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html "1007-  Database already exists"

Comment: MySQL's error 1006 is an error that the database already exists, no?  So calling `CREATE DATABASE company` will fail because it's already present.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the database "company" may already exist.  If you look at the link provided by @Marc B, the error "#1007" corresponds to:

"Error: 1007 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_DB_CREATE_EXISTS)

Message: Can't create database '%s'; database exists

An attempt to create a database failed because the database already exists.

Drop the database first if you really want to replace an existing database, or add an   IF NOT EXISTS clause to the CREATE DATABASE statement if to retain an existing database without having the statement produce an error."

Check your schema to make sure that you don't already have a database called "company" created.

Perhaps you are only trying to create the table "login", whereas you would simply need the code:

```
CREATE TABLE login(
id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

making sure you create this table in the already existing "company" database.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a database that has already been created.

Answer (score 0):

Staring at your two commands, you could do `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

you also need to set default database before creating the table

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS company;
USE company
CREATE TABLE login (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

or you could put the DB name before the table name

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS company;
CREATE TABLE company.login (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: I tried using this, I started by dropping the old company DB and then used the code supplied. It seems the DB is created but the table isn't. It now gives me the 1064 error, could you shed any light on this?

Comment: Changed my code (I changed int(10) to just int), please try again.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE DATABASE university;
USE university;
CREATE TABLE university_info (
department_name VARCHAR(120),
student_name VARCHAR(120),
id INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
gender VARCHAR(100),
age INT,
phone_number INT,
address VARCHAR(120),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

SELECT * FROM university_info;

INSERT INTO university_info (department_name, student_name, id, gender, age, phone_number, address) VALUES
('CSE', 'MD Rubel Rana', 2221081042, 'male', 24, 0140613025, 'gazipur'),
('CSE', 'badhon sorker', 2221081072, 'male', 25, 0195245215, 'gazipur'),
('BBA', 'hossain', 222105245, 'male', 23, 017215346, 'dhaka'),
('LAW', 'pathor', 2356452565, 'female', 25, 01254856, 'Dhaka');

SELECT * FROM university_info;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).